# How can I resume code where I left off after FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION is thrown

Tags: java

I am writing a file into a directory. There might be the chance that the directory becomes unreachable.

What I want to do is..

- As the code is writing to the file, if the directory becomes unreachable or a file not found exception is thrown I want it to keep checking if the directory exists and continue where I left off after the directory exists again.
- After some time if the directory does not come back up then I would shut the program down.

My problem is that when a file not found exception is thrown the program just shuts down all together. Here is my code:

```
public class BusStopsProcessor implements Runnable
{
  private BlockingQueue<Bus<buses>> busQueue;

  private Bus<buses> BusObject; 

  public BusStopsProcessor(BlockingQueue<Bus<buses>> busQueue) 
  {
    this.busQueue = busQueue;
  }

@Override
public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\";         
        File file = new File(path + "busStopsFile.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw, '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

        while(true) 
        {
            BusObject = busQueue.take();

            //each bus object should have a bus date if it does not then it is a 
            //poison bus object. 
            if(BusObject.getBusDate() != null) 
            {
                createBusFile(BusObject, writer);

            else 
            {
                try 
                {
                    //Finished processing bus stops so close writer.
                    writer.close();
                    fw.close();                     

                    break;
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
                    //If a  FILENOTFOUND exception is thrown here I want
                    //my code to be able to pick up where I left off

        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the method that I want to keep checking if the directory exists. If the file is being written into and all of a sudden the directory goes down. I dont want to repeat the same information in the file I want it to continue to write from where it left off but I just cant figure out how to do that. thank you.

```
    private void createBusFile(Bus<buses> aBusObject, CSVWriter writer) throws InterruptedException 
{
    //Get bus information here
    for(Bus<buses> busStop : aBusObject.getBusStops()) 
    {
        busNumber = busStop.getBusNumber();
        busArrivalTime = busStop.getBusArrivalTime();
        busStop = busStop.getBusStop();

        String[] busFields = {busNumber, busDate, busStop};

        //If a file not found exception is thrown here I want it to keep checking if the directory exists. And pick up from where I left off
        writer.writeNext(busFields);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: try surrounding the code with a `try/catch`, it should do what you're asking for

Comment: It's not clear how the program could pick up where it left off.  For example, a write operation is interrupted so the file is corrupt, or at least that line of the file is incomplete.  It would be safer to start over with that file, or somehow keep track of the last successful write and overwrite from that point in the file.  Perhaps another option is to write as a temp file, then copy to the final destination.